# How to fetch data by existing redux action with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand React Hooks. What I want is to fetch data inside functional component by call redux action with useEffect hooks. 
I know that I can pass props to state like

```
 const [todoList] = useState(props.todoList)
```

But what is the best practice to fetch data by existing redux actions?

In React class component i call this method to fetch data in componentDidMount() and everythink works.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { ITodo } from './types'
import { getTodos } from '../actions/todoActions'

interface IProps {
    todoList: Array<ITodo>

    getTodos: typeof getTodos
}


const Todos = (props: IProps) => {

    useEffect(() => {
          props.getTodos()
    }, [props.todoList])



    return (
         <div>
             {props.todoList.map((_) => (<div key={_.Id}>{_.Name}</div>))}
         </div>
      )
 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
     todoList: state.todo.todoList
 })

 const mapDispatchToProps = {
     getTodos
 }


  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProdRoute)
```

I expected to get list of todos with props and props.getTodos() should call once like in componentDidMount() method. But actualy I get data and getTodos() are called over and over again but should be called once on component mount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take care that if you pass `[props.todoList]` to the `useEffect` you are erroneously forcing a constant refresh because:

- `useEffect` does an instance comparison (===) to know if `props.todoList` is changed
- after the the very first render the `props.getTodos()` dispatcher is called
- when the `props.todoList` will be updated the component is re-rendered
- the `useEffect` call will receive `[props.todoList]` as a value to check if it needs to re-run or not
- `props.todoList` is changed (it was empty and now it's valorized) and `props.getTodos()` is so re-called
- redux updates the `todoList` with the same values but mutating the array reference
- the component is re-rendered and the `useEffect` will check if the `[props.todoList]` param is been updated... but IT IS BEEN UPDATED because the previous `props.todoList` is different from the actual `props.todoList`, even if the content is the same

So, if you need to call the `props.getTodos()` just once can

- use `[props.todoList.length]` instead of `[props.todoList]` as the second parameter for the `useEffect` call
- use an empty array `[]` as the second parameter for the `useEffect` call (see [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects))

Comment: Thanks,
I used empty list as second parameter to run once only on mount

Comment: But if you want the provided effect to run every time the props.todoList is changed? Using length is not reliable as the insides might have changed.

Comment: Instead of passing `[props.todoList.length]` to the effect, you can pass `props.todoList.sort().map(_ => _.Id)` (using the same notation of the original example):
1) I sort the array to avoid that [1, 2, 3] and [1, 3, 2] triggers the effect. 2) the `map` call returns an array containing only the ids. 3) all the ids are used as the values to be checked. Let me know if it's not enough clear 